# Why do constant maturity bonds account for modified duration?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, zero-coupon, curve-fitting

One can create a constant maturity treasury (CMT) by building a zero coupon discount curve and generating constant maturity bonds from that curve. This allows one to look further back than is possible with the current 'actual' existing bonds.

I was told that CMT bonds account for modified duration, whereas actual bonds do not. The CMT bond accounts for modified duration precisely because it is created using a zero coupon curve.

Why is this?

Comment: “Account for the modified duration”.  What do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use existing on the run bond yield for analysis. There are at least three ptoblems.

1. The duration is change slightly every day
2. on the run roll cause a yield jump
3. actual yield influenced a lot by liquidy

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing, but they might be talking about the continuity of time series. The chart below shows the modified durations of 10-year par bonds and rolling 10-year on-the-run Treasuries. As you can see, they have the same trends (as expected), but you don't have those jumps (caused by new on-the-run 10-year issues being issued).

[image]